# Macro taking 30 minutes to run please streamline

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort an SAP pull that is around 100k lines long.  The sort is taking 30 minutes to run.  Can you please take a look at this and see if there is anyway I can streamline my sort?

Thanks!

'''

```
Sub Sort_CFG_InvOnHand_Tab()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks("TTB - Inv on hand - CFG_CL")
Set Ws2 = wb.Worksheets("InvOnHand")
Ws2.Activate

 Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "V") = "0" And Cells(i, "X") = "0" Then
            Cells(i, "V").EntireRow.Delete
         End If

       If Left(Cells(i, "H"), 2) = "AA" Or Left(Cells(i, "H"), 2) = "DM" Or Left(Cells(i, "H"), 2) = "MX" Or Left(Cells(i, "I"), 3) = "EFN" Then
           Cells(i, "H").EntireRow.Delete
       End If
    Next i

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(N + 2, "U") = "Total"
    Cells(N + 3, "U") = "Negative Inventory"
    Cells(N + 4, "U") = "Updated Total"
    Cells(N + 6, "U") = "Prior Month Ending"
    Cells(N + 8, "U") = "Difference"
    Cells(N + 2, "V").Formula = "=SUM(V2:V" & N & ")"
    Cells(N + 3, "V").Formula = "=SUMIF(V2:V" & N & ",""<0"")"
    Cells(N + 4, "V") = Cells(N + 1, "V") - Cells(N + 2, "V")
    Cells(N + 2, "X").Formula = "=SUM(X2:X" & N & ")"
    Cells(N + 3, "X").Formula = "=SUMIF(X2:X" & N & ",""<0"")"
    Cells(N + 4, "V") = Cells(N + 1, "V") - Cells(N + 2, "V")
    MsgBox ("Sort Complete")

End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Since this code, most likely better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That said, here are some tips: 1) turn off automatic calculations and turn on/recalc at the end, 2) instead of deleting rows in the loop, collect the rows to delete in a range using union and then run one delete statement after the loop has finished. These two things alone I think will speed up your time tremendously - maybe even to a minute or so.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess my question would be, how do I add a row that meets the criteria to a union?

Comment: Another option is to load all the data into an array, do the sorting in the array, then paste the filtered / sorted data back to the sheet, replacing what was there previously.

Comment: Pull sorted data from SAP!

Comment: The union command worked well.  The sort time dropped to around 45 seconds.  Thanks!